# Connection refused when trying to run Rabbitmq

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, erl

Recently I have installed Rabbitmq 3.6.2 on Ubuntu 14, but whenever i run rabbitmq-server command it gives me error:

```
{error_logger,{{2016,7,5},{13,45,12}},"Protocol: ~tp: register/listen error: ~tp~n",["inet_tcp",econnrefused]}
{error_logger,{{2016,7,5},{13,45,12}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{net_kernel,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.21.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{error,badarg},[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,320}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.10.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[#Port<0.93>,<0.18.0>]},{dictionary,[{longnames,false}]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,376},{stack_size,27},{reductions,805}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2016,7,5},{13,45,12}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{'EXIT',nodistribution}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_kernel},{mfargs,{net_kernel,start_link,[[rabbitmqprelaunch1853,shortnames]]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2016,7,5},{13,45,12}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2016,7,5},{13,45,12}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{pid,<0.9.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,133}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.8.0>]},{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.10.0>,normal}]},{links,[<0.8.0>,<0.7.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,376},{stack_size,27},{reductions,117}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2016,7,5},{13,45,12}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
```

I checked iptables there is no rules in there. I am sure that rabbitmq is not running and port is available. I am not a linux guru, so not sure where to search.

**UPDATED:**

/etc/rabbitmq folder is empty,maybe because it didn't finish the configuration with apt-get (and there is no rabbitmq-env.conf):

```
Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.6.2-1) ...
* Starting message broker rabbitmq-server
* FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_\{log, _err\} [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
rabbitmq-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My ifconfig looks like this (Added xx in the ip address for privacy reasons):

```
 lo Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:2800 (2.8 KB)  TX bytes:2800 (2.8 KB)

 venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7323 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8256 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:919045 (919.0 KB)  TX bytes:1688814 (1.6 MB)

 venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:185.xx.xx.176  P-t-P:185.xx.xx.176  Bcast:185.xx.xx.176  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please report the output of `epmd -debug`

Comment: Here is the output of epmd -debug:  
  
   epmd: Tue Jul  5 15:55:10 2016: epmd running - daemon = 0  
   epmd: Tue Jul  5 15:55:10 2016: error opening stream socket: Address family not supported by protocol  
  
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution would be to download latest ErLang from official website:

https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html

I have downloaded v19 for Ubuntu Precise and now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your loopback interface it seems you disabled IPv6 on your machine (there is no `inet6` entry).

Now, accordingly to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rabbitmq-server/+bug/1312507) `epmd` didn't support IPv6, so they patched it, but now it **requires** IPv6 to be enabled to start (look comments #16 and #17).

Since there is no other activity on that bug, I suggest to try to enable IPv6 on your machine.

A possible workaround is using [IPV4-mapped IPV6 address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses).

Add to your `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` the following line:

```
ERL_EPMD_ADDRESS=::ffff:127.0.1.1
```

**Old answer**

There are a lot of different possible root causes to your error. I suppose you configured RabbitMq to use a IPv6 address, or you have some strange network configuration that doesn't have an IPv4.

I think it worth a shot to try to edit `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` and add:

```
RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS="-proto_dist inet6_tcp"
```

If it doesn't work, please post what else there is in `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` and the output of `ifconfig`, please

Comment: I have updated my question with needed information, thank you.

Comment: @TadasStra if there isn't, please try to create `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` and add the line I wrote in the answer - the installation was OK, just failed the post-install script (because it isn't able to start)

Comment: @TadasStra actually, I updated the answer 'cause I've found a bug that I think is relevant

Comment: I have tried adding the line with ERL_EPMD_ADDRESS and I really thought that would help, but sadly no :( Tried enabling ipv6, but unsuccessfully with message: IPv6 support must be enabled in the kernel. Is there any other solutions? For example downgrade rabbitmq or erl, so it don't need ipv6? Thanks for your support!

Comment: @TadasStra tbh I'm quite short of ideas right now. Just try to do `export ERL_EPMD_ADDRESS=::ffff:127.0.1.1` in the same bash you're launching rabbitmq, maybe rabbitmq doesn't pass it to epmd

Comment: @TadasStra I suggest then to open a bug on LP: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rabbitmq-server/+filebug